# Run Brain JS in headless Node JS script

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, brain.js

I'm looking to run [Brain JS](https://github.com/BrainJS/brain.js#brainjs) in a headless Node JS script, I've tried requiring Brain JS through my `js/run.js` page through NPM, and it errors with: `net.train is not a function`.

```js
const net = require('brain.js')

net.train([
  { input: [0, 0], output: [0] },
  { input: [0, 1], output: [1] },
  { input: [1, 0], output: [1] },
  { input: [1, 1], output: [0] },
])

const output = net.run([1, 0]) // [0.987]
```

Answer (score 0):

You might give this code a go, it should do what you want, using the config from the brain.js docs.

```
const brain = require('brain.js')

// provide optional config object, defaults shown. See brain.js docs for details.
const config = {
  binaryThresh: 0.5,
  hiddenLayers: [3], // array of ints for the sizes of the hidden layers in the network
  activation: 'sigmoid', // supported activation types: ['sigmoid', 'relu', 'leaky-relu', 'tanh'],
  leakyReluAlpha: 0.01, // supported for activation type 'leaky-relu'
}

const net = new brain.NeuralNetwork(config);

net.train([
 { input: [0, 0], output: [0] },
 { input: [0, 1], output: [1] },
 { input: [1, 0], output: [1] },
 { input: [1, 1], output: [0] },
])

for(let input of [[0,0], [0,1], [1,0], [1,1]]) {
    console.log(`Input: [${input[0]},${input[1]}]: output: ${net.run(input)}`);
}
```